# Can one have Python receive a variable-length string array from C#?

Tags: c#, python, dll, ctypes

This may be a red herring, but my non-array version looks like this:

**C#**

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Blah
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [DllExport("printstring", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
        public static string PrintString()
        {
            return "Hello world";
        }
    }
}
```

**Python**

```
import ctypes
dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(“test.dll")
dll.printstring.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
dll.printstring()
```

I am looking for a `printstrings`, which would fetch a `List<string>` of variable size. If that's not possible, I will settle for a fixed-length `string[]`.

Comment: You certainly can't return a List<string>. You could use an array of strings parameter as demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277322/passing-arrays-with-ctypes?rq=1 (but it's more difficult with strings as they are of variable size and need to be allocated on .net side and freed on python side). Otherwise, you could use COM with automation types (instead of DllExport) which could probably be easier (it would be wrapped more automatically).

Comment: For the bounty, I would like to have the code handed to me on a plate ;)

Comment: @DimitriShvorob pythonnet has partial support for .NET collections, including `List`

Answer (score 9):

.NET is capable of transforming the `object` type into COM Automation's [`VARIANT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e305240e-9e11-4006-98cc-26f4932d2118(VS.85)) and the reverse, when going through the p/invoke layer.

VARIANT is declared in python's `automation.py` that comes with [`comtypes`](http://pythonhosted.org/comtypes/).

What's cool with the VARIANT is it's a wrapper that can hold many things, including arrays of many things.

With that in mind, you can declare you .NET C# code like this:

```
[DllExport("printstrings", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static void PrintStrings(ref object obj)
{
    obj = new string[] { "hello", "world" };
}
```

And use it like this in python:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
from comtypes.automation import VARIANT

dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("test")
dll.printstrings.argtypes = [POINTER(VARIANT)]
v = VARIANT()
dll.printstrings(v)
for x in v.value:
  print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you. How about a printStrings that takes an argument? Say printStrings(string separator, ref object obj)?

Comment: @DimitriShvorob - yep, just add an argument to C# and an argument to `argtypes` (this is just a regular python array, enclosed in [ ])

Comment: How to substitute comtypes in Linux? In the example I have an error because comtypes is not supported on Linux. I tried use this on Linux, but VARIANT exists only in comtypes.

Comment: @ÊnioRodrigues - comtypes and VARIANT are Windows only. On non-Windows platform, you cannot marshal object like that, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/type-marshaling#default-rules-for-marshaling-common-types and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/customize-parameter-marshaling#customizing-object-parameters-windows-only

Comment: @SimonMourier I see. Thanks =)