# Calling COM-based function written in C++ using some VARIANT pointer as argument to return a value in Python

Tags: python, com, variant

I have a COM function written in C++ using some VARIANT pointer as argument to return a value.
I want to call that function with **Python** but I run out of solutions;

I tried to use *VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_VARIANT | pythoncom.VT_BYREF, value) from pywin32 and pythonnet python libraries* with no success.

Here is the syntax of the COM function:

```
object.ExtendedGetSourceName(int iSource, VARIANT* ovSourceName) as Boolean
```

with:

```
object: a COM object
iSource: index of the source (starting from 0)
ovSourceName: name of the source
```

*ovSourceName* gets the returned value.

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

xmpmapPath = r"C:\LM.Irradiance.1.xmp"
XMPViewer = win32com.client.Dispatch("XMPViewer.Application") # START INSTANCE
XMPViewer.OpenFile(xmpmapPath)# Opens XMP file
iNbSource = XMPViewer.ExtendedGetNbSource #Returns the number of sources
for sourceindex in range(0, iNbSource):
    sSourceName = win32com.client.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_VARIANT | pythoncom.VT_BYREF, 1)

    RetVal = XMPViewer.ExtendedGetSourceName(sourceindex,  sSourceName) #Returns TRUE if the call has succeeded, FALSE otherwise.
    print(str(RetVal))
    print(str(sSourceName))
```

Visual Studio Codes returns

```
True
win32com.client.VARIANT(16396, 1)
```

Would you know how to make a COM variant pointer, then get its returned in Python?

Comment: See if that doesn't fixes it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481504/403671

Comment: thanks @SimonMourier, I looked at your post and tried to pass VARIANT(), POINTER(VARIANT) from comtypes.automation. I get this error "Objects of type '_ctypes.PyCPointerType' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT"

Comment: I found  [Tim Golden's documentation about VARIANT objects in win32com.client](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/variant.html)